# How to hyphenate "multi-day long"

Tags: hyphenation

I am describing an event that lasts for more than 68 continuous hours, and I want to describe it as a "multi-day long" event, but I don't know where to put the hypen(s) in that phrase.

Comment: The "long" seems unnecessary. It is a multi-day event lasting more than 68 continuous hours.

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating a noun phrase, drop the "long" and simply call it a "multi-day event".

Alternately, consider "the event spans multiple days" or (less elegantly) "the event is multiple days long".

Answer (score 0):

Technically speaking, it's not wrong to hyphenate it as a *multi-day-long event*.

You can have a *day-long event*, so *multi* is simply added to the start of the compound adjective. However, that does look a little strange.

In addition to the other solutions, you can also call it a *days-long event*. This, too, is a bit strange, but still correct.

Comment: Sixty-eight hours is just under three 24-hour days, so why not call it a "three-day event"?